# Defining Route for Composite Primary Keys in WebAPI2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, composite-primary-key, asp.net-web-api-routing

How can I define composite PKs in my WebAPI Controller? I have 2 entities. In one of them I have two Primary Keys.

The Entity "Person" has the following properties: Id (PK), Lname (PK), Fname, Age, GroupId (FK).

Here is my Controller code:

```
// GET: api/Person/5
[HttpGet]
[Route("Id")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Person))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetPersonById(int id, string lname)
{
    Person person = await db.Persons.FindAsync(new object[] {id, lname});
    if (person == null)
    {
       return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(person);
}
```

Entity Person:

```
public partial class Person
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string lname { get; set; }
  public string fname { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }

  public int GroupId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Id")]
  public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

Do I have to define the lname also in the Route DataAnnotation?

Comment: Are you speaking about entity framework? How to set composite primary key in it? BTW, your class Person is strange... The foreign key field of the Group is Id and not GroupId?

Comment: @bubi Yes I've created the Model with Entity Framework. But the DataAnnotations I've defined separately. Yes I'm using the Foreign Key from the object Group which is containing with the properties of the group entity.